# Текст по краям и изображение по центру

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать так, чтобы текст был по краям, а  изображение по центру?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно с помощью `flex`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper,
.text,
img {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.text::before {
  content: "\25BA";
  color: crimson;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore cumque, odio consequatur, dolores hic a perferendis nemo ab temporibus ex quia aliquam molestiae explicabo? Reiciendis cupiditate perferendis aspernatur quos odio.</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi placeat reiciendis laudantium similique totam quaerat numquam veritatis qui vitae eveniet, voluptates debitis necessitatibus, iusto exercitationem nostrum adipisci cum cumque illum.</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A rem eveniet molestias maxime odio. Fugit ea tenetur dolores facilis, quos laborum omnis est sint beatae illo distinctio? Natus, maxime aspernatur!</div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x250" alt="1">
  <div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, sed distinctio. A voluptate minima repellat voluptatibus maiores! Dolore eveniet laudantium, autem molestiae asperiores laboriosam unde perferendis deserunt, harum temporibus quidem.</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur tempora, neque dolores cupiditate facilis error rem totam, repellendus suscipit magnam, porro esse possimus! Quasi cumque eligendi maiores, tempora laudantium et!</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat enim quo at ut. Nemo optio eveniet ducimus nesciunt, voluptate necessitatibus voluptas reprehenderit numquam consequatur, animi rem nam odit qui maiores?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хороший ответ, адаптивность реализована

Comment: А если элемент который before захочу подвинуть левее как сделать чтоб не выходил за экран и у правого блока не налезал на картинку?*

Comment: @Олег, изменил ответ.

Comment: @Олег, если вам помог ответ, не забудьте отметить его решением